# C# - How to pass and run a method in a function?

Tags: c#, function, testing, parameters, wrapper

I'm trying to write a wrapper for a Selenium test that re-runs the test if it fails, I've got the mechanics working fine. But I need to figure out a way of passing either a function/method or (preferably) multiple methods inside of the function. Here's an example of what I want to achieve:

In the wrapper class:

```
public class TestRunner{
    public void RunTest(function FuncToRun){
        FuncToRun();        
    }
}
```

In the test:

```
public class Tests{
    public void Test(){
        ...Run test methods...
    }
TestRunner.RunTest(Test());
}
```

**This is purely for demonstration**. I know that this doesn't work, but I hope it will convey my point to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks as though you need a [delegate](http://youtu.be/rxLNJ8jCN1c).

An applicable delegate for your scenario is the [`Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action(v=vs.110).aspx) delegate which can be used to represent a single parameterless method.

```
public class TestRunner
{
    public void RunTests(params Action[] tests)
    {
        foreach (var test in tests)
        {
            test.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

Note the use of the `params` keyword which will allow you ro supply any number of tests to the `RunTests` method. Here is an example using an implicit method group conversion:

```
public class Tests
{
    public void TestOne() {
    }

    public void TestTwo() {
    }
}

...
var runner = new TestRunner();
var tests = new Tests();
runner.RunTests(tests.TestOne, tests.TestTwo);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action(v=vs.110).aspx) parameters to do this

```
public class TestRunner{
    public void RunTest(Action FuncToRun){
        FuncToRun();        
    }
}

public class Tests{
    public void Test(){
        ...Run test methods...
    }
    TestRunner.RunTest(() => Test());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to do something like this. But need more context as in inputs and what return value you are expecting.

```
   Func<string, int> myMethodName
```

This is an example of usage:

```
   public bool RunThisMethod(Func<string, int> myMethod)
    {
        //... do stuff
        int i = myMethod("My String");
        //... do more stuff
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use delegate . simply declare a delegate to the method you want to pass and call and assign the method to it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms173171.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You may use delegates or even Action or Func objects.

```
public class TestRunner{
    public void RunTest(Action funcAction){
        funcAction();        
    }
}

public class Tests{
    public void Test(){}
    TestRunner.RunTest(Test);
}
```